# the letter "l" no longer works in the terminal

Tags: command-line

I have a problem with my Ubuntu terminal. I cannot type the letter l in the terminal anymore. In the other programs and also in the internet the letter works. I have also tried it with another keyboard. Can you help me?

Comment: What happens when you press that key?

Comment: it is not displayed

Comment: What changed in your system immediately before this problem occurred?

Comment: nothing has changed before, everything has worked

Answer (score 1):

I think I've seen something like this and it was caused by an incorrect readline config. Remove ~/.inputrc, reopen your shell and try again.

Comment: Yeah, it sounds like the letter "I" is bound to a command shortcut instead of just typing the character. So it would be something in readline (.inputrc) or bash keybinding config (.bashrc or .bash_aliases if that contains keybindings).

Comment: what kind of command would be